# Почему  не позиционируется посередине?

Tags: html5, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <style> body, html, h1, header, div { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; } body { background-image: url(backround-images.png); font: 14px "Open Sans Light"; cursor: default; } h1 { font-weight: normal; } div { width: 905px; margin: 30px auto; } nav a { background-image: url(fake_brick.png); color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 3px 10px; } nav { width: 880px; margin: 10px auto; position: absolute; } </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <header><h1>Официальный новостной и мультимедийный сайт Ельцовской СОШ</h1>    </header>
        <nav><a href=index.html>Домой</a><a href=AbouttheSchool.html>О школе</a><a href=teachers.html>Учителям</a><a href=pupils.html>Ученикам</a><a href=activity.html>Мероприятия</a><a href=parents.html>Родителям</a><a href=photo.html>Проекты</a><a href=news.html>Новости</a><a href=contacts.html>Контакты</a><a href=help.html>Помощь</a><a href=about.html>О сайте</a></nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если вам надо менюшку оцентровать, то уберите position: absolute; и поставьте margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял, о чем вопрос. Возможно, это ответ

```
<div align="center">Ваш код</div>
```

или

```
<center> код </center>
```

Пример

```
<div align="center">
<header><h1>Официальный новостной и мультимедийный сайт Ельцовской СОШ</h1></header>
<nav>
<a href=index.html>Домой</a><a href=AbouttheSchool.html>О школе</a>
<a href=teachers.html>Учителям</a><a href=pupils.html>Ученикам</a>
<a href=activity.html>Мероприятия</a><a href=parents.html>Родителям</a>
<a href=photo.html>Проекты</a><a href=news.html>Новости</a>
<a href=contacts.html>Контакты</a><a href=help.html>Помощь</a>
<a href=about.html>О сайте</a>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Я использую HTML а такой тег как center уже устарел, так же как и атрибут align

Comment: @VladimirVi, устарел? лол. Устарел - значит не работает? Или не кроссбраузерный? Или есть еще хоть какая-нибудь обьективная причина принципиально не использовать эти компоненты?

Comment: Он работает, но он устарел, я имел в виду. почему в моей версии страницы margin: 0 auto; не работает?

Comment: Почему в вашей *"версии страницы margin: 0 auto; не работает"*? Потому, что у вас знаний не хватает, зато начитавшись блогов го*нокодеров, начинаете рассуждать об устаревших тегах.

Comment: Да, тэг <center> не поддерживается в html5, а атрибут align - deprecated.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov , да не в тегах дело и не в HTML5, а про CSS. Самый первый мой коментарий - я попытался натолкнуть на путь истинный убрать **position: absolute;**. Или может где появилась статья "HTML5 центрируем объекты с абсолютным позиционированием легко и не принуждённо с помощью margin: 0 auto;"?

Comment: @Deonis, элемент с position: absolute можно центрировать с помощью margin: auto, если задать нулевые значения всем координатам, учите матчасть.
@Crasher, писать код, чтобы понимал браузер может любой дурак. Дело не в поддержке браузером, а в том, что нужно разделять дизайн и разметку. Вы сами себе усложняете работу, если используете HTML-теги и атрибуты для оформления.

Answer (score 0):

А [так](http://we-like-children.ru/test.html) тоже не работает?